# Sorting array keeping even values on top PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have tried sorting the below array to keep the even values on top and in sorted order from `asc` to `desc`

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
```

I tried this to sort the array

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { 
                    if ($a % 2 == 0 )
                    { 
                        return 1 ;
                    }
                    else 
                    { 
                        return -1;
                    }
            }
        );
```

I got the output like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 9
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 5
    [4] => 3
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 6
    [8] => 8
    [9] => 10
)
```

And I want the output array to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 6
    [3] => 8
    [4] => 10
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 3
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 7
    [9] => 9
)
```

The even and odd values should be sorted in asc to desc order but keep the even values on top of odd values

Comment: So perhaps you realise that you've got the return values in your callback function reversed; but you'll also need a secondary check to sort the evens in ascending and the odds in ascending order

Comment: @MarkBaker: That is what I don't know how to perform. I can't figure out how to code it in the callback

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`usort` is not [stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). The documentation states:

> If two members compare as equal, their relative order in the sorted array is undefined.

So, what you can do is:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
                if ($a % 2 == $b % 2) {
                    return intval($a - $b);
                }
                elseif ($a % 2 == 0 )
                { 
                    return -1 ;
                }
                else 
                { 
                    return 1;
                }
        }
    );
```

This compares the actual values if both are even or both are odd.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need a somewhat more complex function. Because when you look at it there are different cases to take care of and in every one of them something different must happen:

- `$a` and `$b` both are even: default numeric comparison
- `$a` and `$b` both are odd: default numeric comparison
- `$a` is even, `$b` is odd: `$a` is always smaller than `$b`
- `$a` is odd, `$b` is even: `$b` is always smaller than `$a`

And for the implementation see the [answer of fab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767875/989169).

Comment: You want to explain the downvote to me? I feel like the given answers lack explanation and that's why I posted my answer in spite of others being faster...I just left out writing any code, because there are already enough answers containing that.

Comment: I agree there was no reason to downvote. Personally I prefer to inspire asking person to think rather then giving him ready solution.

Answer (score 2):

A bit lenghty but works fine for me:

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$even =array();

$odd = array();

foreach ($array as $item) {

  if($item%2==0) {

    $even[] = $item;
  }

  else {

    $odd[] = $item;

  }

}

usort($even);

usort($odd);

$array_sort = array_merge($even,$odd);

print_r($array_sort);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { 
                    if ($a % 2 == $b % 2) {
                           if ($a == $b) {
                               return 0;
                           }
                           return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
                    } elseif ($a % 2 == 0) { 
                        return -1 ;
                    } else { 
                        return 1;
                    }
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and simple way to write it:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
usort($array, function($a, $b){
  if ($a % 2 == $b % 2) {
    return $a - $b;
  }
  return $a % 2 != 0;
});
print_r($array);
?>
```

or with a ternary:

```
<?php
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
usort($array, function($a, $b){
  return ($a % 2 == $b % 2) ? ($a - $b) : ($a % 2 != 0);
});
print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the comparison function, first take the difference of the mod 2 values of the two numbers.

It will be -1, 0, or 1. If it's not zero, then one number is even and the other is odd, so you can return that value. (That will sort odds above evens.)

If it is zero, then either both numbers are even or both numbers are odd, and you need to take the difference of the two numbers to break the tie.

A concise way to write this is:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a % 2 - $b % 2 ?: $a - $b;
});
```

---

To sort odd numbers at the beginning instead, swap `$a` and `$b` in the first comparison.

```
return $b % 2 - $a % 2 ?: $a - $b;
```